# Laravel Query Filter different Tables with AND

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with my Larvel Query it doesn't work as desired.
It should Filter "Campaigns" with the attributes Teams, Channels, Region and Timeperiod with Start and Enddate. The Timeperiod is no problem.

The user can Filter for differen Teams/Channels/Region and can choose no, one or more Attribute, which should connect as or.

The desired Result should give all Campaign which has the selected Teams AND Channels AND Region. But at the moment I get every Campaign which has the selected Teams OR the selected Channels OR the selected Region.

```
public function searchCampaigns($page, $limit, $data)
{
    $startDate = $data['startDate'];
    $endDate = $data['endDate'];

    $campaigns = Campaign::distinct()->select('campaigns.*')
                ->join('campaign_team', 'campaign_team.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id')
                ->join('campaign_region', 'campaign_region.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id')
                ->join('campaign_channel', 'campaign_channel.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id')
                ->join('teams', 'campaign_team.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
                ->join('regions', 'campaign_region.region_id', '=', 'regions.id')
                ->join('channels', 'campaign_channel.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id')
//Interesting Part
                ->whereIn('teams.id', $data['teams'])
                ->whereIn('regions.id', $data['regions'])
                ->whereIn('channels.id', $data['channels'])
                ->where(function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                    $query->where('campaigns.start_date', '>=', $startDate)
                        ->where('campaigns.end_date', '<=', $endDate);
                })

                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                    $query->where('campaigns.end_date', '<=', $endDate)
                        ->where('campaigns.end_date', '>=', $startDate);
                })

                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                    $query->where('campaigns.start_date', '>=', $startDate)
                        ->where('campaigns.start_date', '<=', $endDate);
                })

                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                    $query->where('campaigns.start_date', '<=', $startDate)
                        ->Where('campaigns.end_date', '>=', $endDate);
                })                    ->orderBy('start_date', 'asc');

    $result['count'] = sizeof($campaigns->lists('id'));
    $result['campaigns'] = $campaigns->skip($limit * ($page - 1))->take($limit)->get();

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. It shall work. Let me know if any issues happen :)

```
public function searchCampaigns($page, $limit, $data)
{
    $result = [];     

    // Checking Validity of Start Date
    if (empty($data['startDate']) || (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['startDate']) === false))
        return $result;

    // Checking Validity of End Date                
    if (empty($data['endDate']) || (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['endDate']) === false))
        return $result;                 

    // Comparing Start & End Date
    $startDate = Carbon::parse($data['startDate']);
    $endDate = Carbon::parse($data['endDate']);

    if($startDate->gt($endDate))
        return $result;

    if($endDate->lt($startDate))
        return $result;

    $startDate = $data['startDate'];
    $endDate = $data['endDate'];                        

    $campaigns = Campaign::distinct()->select('campaigns.*')
                ->join('campaign_team', 'campaign_team.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id')
                ->join('campaign_region', 'campaign_region.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id')
                ->join('campaign_channel', 'campaign_channel.campaign_id', '=', 'campaigns.id')
                ->join('teams', 'campaign_team.team_id', '=', 'teams.id')
                ->join('regions', 'campaign_region.region_id', '=', 'regions.id')
                ->join('channels', 'campaign_channel.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id')
                ->whereIn('teams.id', $data['teams'])
                ->whereIn('regions.id', $data['regions'])
                ->whereIn('channels.id', $data['channels'])
                ->where('campaigns.start_date', '>=', $startDate)
                ->where('campaigns.end_date', '<=', $endDate);
                ->orderBy('start_date', 'asc');

    $result['count'] = sizeof($campaigns->lists('id'));
    $result['campaigns'] = $campaigns->skip($limit * ($page - 1))->take($limit)->get();

    return $result;
}
```